# Nsight report: No kernel launches captured

Tags: cuda, nsight

I wrote a simple cuda program in a .cu file. When I want to see the performance of this program. I choose "Nsight->Start Performance Analysis...." Then choose "Profile CUDA Application". After launching the application for a while and finishing capture, the report say "No kernel launches captured" The summary report say" 1 error encountered". Can someone help me to figure out why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

Do you call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaDeviceReset()` after all the CUDA work is done in your sample? Otherwise Nsight cannot guarantee that all the launch and memcpy record buffers are flushed.